# Database Exception in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

please help mee, can you tell me way ?

```
$totalah = Sah::find()
      ->select('mhs, SUM(IF(status_kehadiran = 1,status_kehadiran , 0))AS K3211335')
      ->where([
           'kode_mk'=> 'K3211335'
      ])
      ->groupBy('mhs')
      ->all();

 echo "<pre/>"; print_r($totalah);
 die;
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `K3211335`
> FROM `sah` WHERE `kode_mk`='K3211335' GROUP BY `mhs' at line 1 The SQL being executed was: SELECT` mhs`, SUM(IF(status_kehadiran = 1,` status_kehadiran`,` 0))AS`AS`K3211335`FROM`simak_absen_harian`WHERE`kode_mk`='K3211335' GROUP BY` mhs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple data in select you can use array. You also need a space before AS:

```
 $totalah = Sah::find()
  ->select(['mhs', 'SUM(IF(status_kehadiran = 1,status_kehadiran , 0)) AS K3211335'])
  ->where([
       'kode_mk'=> 'K3211335'
  ])
  ->groupBy('mhs')
  ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you purpose, you sum `status_kehadiran` when `status_kehadiran = 1`, why you don't just `SUM status_kehadiran where status_kehadiran = 1`

```
$totalah = Sah::find()
  ->select(['mhs', 'SUM(status_kehadiran) AS K3211335'])
  ->where([
       'kode_mk'=> 'K3211335',
       'status_kehadiran' => 1
  ])
  ->groupBy('mhs')
  ->all();
```